# Alternative to fig.sh for node.js?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, fig

Currently I'm looking to an alternative to fig.sh but for node.js (or heroku style). Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want a Fig like behavior (for Docker) but something that doesn't have Python as a dependency?

Comment: Can I run a node.js project with fig?

Comment: you should be able to, see https://github.com/b00giZm/fig-nodejs-examples

Answer (score 0):

Without additional details on what it is that you are actually looking for, the best I've got for you is to checkout [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku).